# How to change border color from the ion-header

Tags: css, sass, colors, ionic3, border

I'm developing a new app using Ionic 3 but I would like to change the border color from the header but I don't know how to do it.

Any help please?

My HTML file:

```
<ion-header no-shadow class="nav-content">
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>
      MEDITACIÓN
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="close" color="third"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content">
</ion-content>
```

My sass file:

```
page-meditation {
  .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .toolbar {
    border-color: red !important;
    // box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ff9100!important;
  }

  .content {
    background-color: color($colors, primary, base);
  }
}
```

If I put border-color it doesn't work. And if a put box-shadow, works but the line is draw below the other border and thicker with 1px.

Comment: You want to change the border color of the header, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a Ionic app's header looks like this :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Page1</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Subheader</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**css**

```
 .toolbar{
       border-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my post because I tested your approach but it doesn't work. I added my code for more details.